# Prestashop 1.6 Country localization, address format not working

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I'm attempting to localize a prestashop 1.6 website to be local to Gambia. I've configured the system as follows to only have mobile_phone in the address field

**Localization > Countries**
[image: Country localization form for gambia]

**Localization > Configuration**
[image]

**account creation**
[image]

I've disabled all other countries than Gambia.

If I click on "Use My modified format" or I don't click on any of those buttons I get the same result of too many undesired address fields.

Some references:

- [How to set the default language and localization](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/prestashop-1-6-x-how-to-set-the-default-language-and-localization.html)
- [How to configure customer billing address to remove fields](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/458023-how-to-configure-customer-billing-address-to-remove-fields/)

What am I doing wrong?

Regards Conteh